# Why C++ destructor at inheritance invoked 2 times

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
A(){cout<<"A();";}
 ~A(){cout<<"~A();";}
};

class B : public A {
public:
B(){cout<<"B();";}
 ~B(){cout<<"~B();";}
};

int main() {
A a =B();
return 0;
}
```

Output:
A();B();~B();~A();~A();

Why is A's destructor invoked 2 times?

Comment: You have copy-contructor and slicing...

Answer (score 5):

After you create a temporary object, which is being copied into `a` (with [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)!) the first destruction starts. A temporary object (`B();`) is being destructed - first `~B()` and then the destructor of its parent class `~A()` is called. Then `a` goes out of scope and its destructor fires.